# AMD GPU Fan Control

Tags: fan, gpu

I have installed ubuntu 16.04 and my GPU is R9 380X. The Driver used is AMDGPU..is there any way to control the fan of my gpu? because it never spins.

Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is. There is a link on a git project: https://github.com/DominiLux/amdgpu-pro-fans